# Llamar a una función mediante un array en vez de los argumentos

Tags: javascript, parámetros

Normalmente, para agregar tres valores a un array hago esto.

```
var array=[]
array.push(10,20,30)
console.log(array) //[10,20,30]
```

Pero yo quiero que `push` agregue los valores al array, pero desde otro array. Si yo intento lo siguiente, me devuelve el segundo array, metido dentro del primer array.

```
var array=[]
var otro_array=[10,20,30]
array.push(otro_array)
console.log(array) //[[10,20,30]]
```

Una solución que se me ocurrió fue hacer una función que reciba un array, y los vaya pasando como argumento a push.

Pero la única manera que sé hacerlo es con muchas líneas, escribiendo los valores uno por uno.

```js
function agrega_desde_array(array,otro_array)
{
  return array.push(
    otro_array[0],
    otro_array[1],
    otro_array[2]
  )
}

var array=[]
var otro_array=[10,20,30]
agrega_desde_array(array,otro_array)
console.log("Array es: "+array)
```

Esto, además tiene varios problemas, uno es que está limitada la cantidad de argumentos. Otro problema es que no se adapta a la longitud de `otro_array`.

¿Existe alguna manera de no tener que escribir los argumentos uno por uno? Es decir, me gustaría que los tome desde el array.

**Nota:** No quiero agregar los elementos, llamando varias veces a `push`, es decir, primero `array.push(10)`, luego `array.push(20)`, eso no es lo que busco. Quiero que la función `push` sea llamada una sola vez.

Comment: `function agrega_desde_array (array, otro) { [].push.apply(array, otro) }`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Esa función me funciona perfectamente. Estaría bueno si haces una respuesta con eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado un array vacío puedes inicializarlo con los elementos de otro array utilizando [slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), función que al no indicarle extremos retorna una copia del array.

```js
let array=[]
let otro_array=[10,20,30]
array = otro_array.slice(); 
console.log(array) //[10,20,30]
```

Si lo que te interesa es no perder los elementos del array original sino concatenar ambos arrays puedes utilizar [concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp), solo tienes que tener la precausión de reasignar el resultado de `concat()` a tu array, ya que esta función no modifica el array original sino que retorna la concatenación como resultado

**EDIT: ES6 Spread Syntax**:

En ECMAScript6 es posible utilizar [spread syntax (...args)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Este operador permite por ejemplo que elementos que son iterables pueden ser expandidos en la llamada a la función

```
someFunction(...array); --- > someFunction(1, 2, 3);
```

Por ende es lo mismo hacer

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
array.push(10,20,30);
console.log(array) //[1,2,3,10,20,30]
```

que:

```js
let array=[1,2,3]
let otro_array=[10,20,30]
array.push(...otro_array);
console.log(array) //[1,2,3,10,20,30]
```

Comment: Aunque la respuesta tiene información interesante, no era esa la intención de mi pregunta. La idea es crear una función que le pase todos los argumentos a `push`.

Comment: Investigando un poco encontré algo interesante, he editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Function#prototype#apply`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply) es una vieja y útil solución:

```js
var to = []
var from = [1, 2, 3]

addFromArray(to, from)

console.log(to)

function addFromArray (to, from) {
  // to --> Es el valor que tomará como this la función push
  // from --> Array de elementos a los que aplicar la función push
  [].push.apply(to, from)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> La idea es crear una función que le pase todos los argumentos a push

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
const source = [5, 15, 25];

const concat = (origin, target) => {
  target.forEach(e => origin.push(e));
};

concat(source, [10, 20, 30]);
console.log(source);
```

Si usas ES6 puedes hacer uso de rest params:

```js
const source = [5, 15, 25];
const concat = (origin, ...els) => {
  els.forEach(e => origin.push(e));
};
concat(source, 10, 20, 30);
console.log(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es esto lo que estas buscando

```
function agrega_desde_array(array,otro_array) {
      for(i = 0; i<otro_array.length;i++){
         array.push(otro_array[i]);
      }
      return array
}

var array=[];
var otro_array=[10,20,30];
array = agrega_desde_array(array,otro_array);
console.log("Array es: "+array);
```

Comment: Esto es justamente lo que no quería, según lo que puse en la **Nota**. Al poner `push` dentro del array, está llamando varias veces a `push`.